# Wavy arrow with color shading

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-arrows, gradient

I would like to create a wavy arrow with a color gradient along the wave. For this, I tried to combine the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197867/96546 for color gradients with the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193451/96546 for wavy arrows.

Here is a MWE:

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}
    \makeatletter
    \def\createshadingfromlist#1#2#3{%
        \pgfutil@tempcnta=0\relax
        \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{\advance\pgfutil@tempcnta by1}%
        \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcnta=1\relax%
        \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(#3);color(100)=(#3)}%
        \else%
        \pgfmathparse{50/(\pgfutil@tempcnta-1)}\let\pgf@step=\pgfmathresult%
        %
        \pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
        \pgfutil@for\pgf@tmp:={#3}\do{%
            \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb=1\relax%
            \edef\pgf@spec{color(0)=(\pgf@tmp);color(25)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
            \else%
            \ifnum\pgfutil@tempcntb<\pgfutil@tempcnta\relax%
            \pgfmathparse{25+\pgf@step/4+(\pgfutil@tempcntb-1)*\pgf@step}%
            \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(\pgfmathresult)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
            \else%
            \edef\pgf@spec{\pgf@spec;color(75)=(\pgf@tmp);color(100)=(\pgf@tmp)}%
            \fi%
            \fi%
            \advance\pgfutil@tempcntb by1\relax%
        }%
        \fi%
        \csname pgfdeclare#2shading\endcsname{#1}{100}\pgf@spec%
    }
    
    \createshadingfromlist{shading1}{vertical}{red,yellow,green,cyan,blue}
    \createshadingfromlist{shading2}{vertical}{red,yellow}
    \createshadingfromlist{shading3}{vertical}{black,blue,cyan,white}
    
    %%%
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usepackage[compat=1.0.0]{tikz-feynman}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
    %\usetkzobj{all}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
    
    \begin{document}
        \tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
            {decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[colorbar arrow/.style={
                shape=double arrow,
                double arrow head extend=0.125cm, 
                shape border rotate=90, 
                minimum height=5cm,
                shading=#1
            },
            wavy/.style={decorate,decoration={snake,post length=1.2mm}}
            ]
            
            \node [colorbar arrow=shading1,wavy] at (0,0) {};
    %       \node [colorbar arrow=shading2] at (1,0) {};
    %       \node [colorbar arrow=shading3] at (2,0) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}  
    \end{document}
```

which creates the following figure:
[image]

So it almost works, but somehow the ends are not really arrows any more and the wave modifies both sides of the arrow boundary. What I would like to create is something like

[image]

with a color gradient across. This can be obtained in the above MWE by replacing the `\node` line with `\draw[red,wavy,->,>=stealth'] (5.0,0.2) -- (2.2,0.2) node [above] {};`

Any hints on what is going wrong in this combination or how to do it properly appreciated!

Comment: Hi!  What do you need to control in the end?  The start and end points I suppose, and the color gradient.  But, is the number of "waves" important?  Or their amplitude?  Do you need to control them?  What about the line width?

Comment: @DanielN hm, I guess it would be nice to be able to control all of these (you can control most of them in the solution that I linked). Any intermediate solution would potentially be valuable too though if it still looks reasonably like a wavy arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I propose a solution in which the wavy path and the colour change are realized at the same time through a loop and the sin function; there is no decoration involved.

The arrow is a `pic` object, `w arrow`, that depends on six arguments: the starting and ending points, the amplitude of the "wave", the number of (complete) periods, the starting and ending colours.

**Remark.** In case you need a gradient with more than two colors, then the colors must be given as a list.  The modification is minimal.  We can talk about it if you need it.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\tikzset{%
  pics/w arrow/.style args={from=#1 to=#2, amplitude=#3, periods=#4,
    s-color=#5, e-color=#6%
  }{%
    code={%
      \tikzmath{%
        integer \nbSteps, \i, \j;
        real \d, \r, \angle, \nbPeriods, \h, \ecst, \acst;
        coordinate \S, \E;
        \nbPeriods = #4 +.75;
        \nbSteps = 25;
        \S = #1;
        \E = #2;
        \d = veclen(\Ex-\Sx, \Ey-\Sy)*1pt/1cm;
        \acst = .65;  % controls the horizontal segment supporting the arrow
        \r = \d/(\nbPeriods +\acst);
        \ecst = (\nbPeriods +.3)/(\nbPeriods +\acst);
        \angle = atan2(\Ey-\Sy, \Ex-\Sx);
        \h = \nbPeriods/\nbSteps;  % domain length for \x
        \a = 0;
        \b = \a +\h;
        for \i in {1,...,\nbSteps}{%
          \j = 4*\i;
          {%
            \draw[#6!\j!#5, line cap=round,
            domain=\a:\b, samples=15, shift={(\S)}, rotate=\angle]
            plot ({\r*\x}, {-#3*sin(360*\x)});
          };
          \a = \b;
          \b = \a +\h;
        };
        {%
          \path[shift={(\S)}, rotate=\angle]
          ({\r*\nbPeriods}, {-#3*sin(360*\nbPeriods)})
          coordinate (tmpPoint);
          \draw[#6, ->] (tmpPoint)           
          to[out=\angle, in=\angle+180] ($(\S)!\ecst!(\E)$) -- (\E);
        };
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \draw[fill=gray!20] (0, 0) circle (1.5pt) node[left] {$S$};
  \draw[fill=gray!20] (3, 1) circle (1.5pt) node[right] {$E$};

  \path pic[very thick]
  {w arrow={from=(0, 0) to=(3, 1), amplitude=.2, periods=3,
      s-color=green, e-color=blue}};
  \path pic[]
  {w arrow={from=(0, -.5) to=(4, -.5), amplitude=.1, periods=5,
      s-color=cyan, e-color=red}};
  \path pic[line width=4pt]
  {w arrow={from=(0, -.5) to=(4, -3), amplitude=.3, periods=2,
      s-color=cyan, e-color=violet}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```